# Fixed position sidebar that stops at the footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have seen this question a few times on here, but have not found one that has a good answer yet, so I figured I would ask again.

I have a sidebar that is fixed position to the top of my document, which breaks the element out of normal html flow.

When we scroll to the bottom where my footer is, I would like the sidebar to be pushed up with the footer.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>link</li>
      <li>link</li>
      <li>link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>content of unspecified height</p>
  <p>content of unspecified height</p>
  <p>content of unspecified height</p>
  <p>content of unspecified height</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#sidebar {
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#footer {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
...?
```

I imagine what needs to happen is when the bottom of the "content" div scrolls on to the screen, then the JS will switch the sidebar position to absolute or relative to the bottom of that div, so it can go back to normal flow.. but I am open to suggestions to the best approach.

Edit: Oh yes, and when the page scrolls back up, the sidebar will need to go back to the fixed top positioning- just in case it wasn't obvious :)

Still am new to JS and JQuery, which is another reason some of the existing answers didn't quite click for me.

Thanks for any input! Let me know if I need to clarify or correct anything.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `$(window).on('scroll')` function that compares the top of the footer to the bottom the window. Psuedo-code:

```
//Make the height of side nav shrink as we scroll past the footer
var intPos = TopOfFooter - BottomOfWindow
If (intPos < 0) {
   var newHeight = $(window).height() + intPos // intPos is negative so will take away
   $('#sidebar').height(newHeight);
} else {
   $('#sidebar').height('100%');
}
```

Or something to that effect...

**EDIT**

FYI:

```
var TopOfFooter = $('#footer').offset().top;
var BottomOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
```

Comment: That code seems like it can work, but rather than shrinking the height of the sidebar, perhaps it would make more sense to toggle a new class to the element that has the updated positioning?  SInce I am not using any specified heights on my container elements, then a 100% height will not work?

Comment: Sure thing, just change accordingly. Reducing the height is just what I would do. :)